# What is the right way to implement generic computation algorithms in Rust?

Tags: rust

It is quite a nuisance to implement a generic computation algorithm in Rust. It feels like I am reinventing all the stuff not in the algorithm, but in the codomain of Church numerals.

For example, here's an implementation of `factorial` that works in Rust 1.7:

```
#![feature(zero_one)]

use std::num::{One, Zero};
use std::ops::{Sub, Mul};
use std::cmp::Eq;

fn fact<T>(n: T) -> T
    where T: Clone + Eq + Zero + One + Mul<T, Output = T> + Sub<T, Output = T>
{
    if n == T::zero() {
        T::one()
    } else {
        fact(n.clone() - T::one()) * n
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", fact(10));
}
```

Is there any right way of doing this? Is there any discussion going on with it?

---

Probably `factorial` is not good example, let's try `is_even`:

```
fn is_even<T>(x: T) -> bool
    where T: std::ops::Rem<Output = T> + std::ops::Add<T, Output=T> + std::num::One + std::num::Zero + std::cmp::PartialEq
{
    let two = T::one() + T::one();
    (x % two) == T::zero()
}
```

If you want a `two` stuff, you must reimplement two.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a narrowly-targeted question that Stack Overflow can answer. "How do I implement a generic algorithm" is an *extremely* broad topic. Your code, as written, looks like the definition of a factorial as I would expect. *To me*, your question reads more of a rant than a well-meaning question, but that's likely just my personal interpretation.

Comment: @Shepmaster If `factorial` looks find, how about this `is_even`?

Comment: You could reduce the bounds by using the traits in the [num crate](https://github.com/rust-num/num) but the implementations would remain the same. How would you expect a generic implementation of is_even to look ideally?

Comment: @PaoloFalabella It seems that there's no safe way of doing it. `is_even` looks completely like Church numerals now and how about sorting or matrix algorithms. Probably there's no easy way of implementing these stuffs without unsafe?

Comment: It's not a matter of not being able to do it safely, more that it's difficult to model generic numeric programming. There have been attempts and multiple discussions before. I refer you to this [discussion on reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3wubj0/numeric_types_in_rust/) that sums it up nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to implement `is_even` I would obviously start by implementing `is_divisible` which is more generic:

```
#![feature(zero_one)]

use std::cmp;
use std::num;
use std::ops;

fn is_divisible<T>(x: T, by: T) -> bool
    where T: ops::Rem<Output = T> + num::Zero + cmp::PartialEq
{
    (x % by) == T::zero()
}
```

It seems easy enough.

However, `is_even` has even more constraints and this is getting a bit long, so let's follow DRY:

```
trait Arithmetic:
    From<u8> +
    cmp::PartialEq + cmp::Eq + cmp::PartialOrd + cmp::Ord +
    ops::Add<Self, Output = Self> + ops::Sub<Self, Output = Self> +
    ops::Mul<Self, Output = Self> + ops::Div<Self, Output = Self> + ops::Rem<Self, Output = Self> {}

impl<T> Arithmetic for T
    where T: From<u8> +
             cmp::PartialEq + cmp::Eq + cmp::PartialOrd + cmp::Ord +
             ops::Add<T, Output = T> + ops::Sub<T, Output = T> +
             ops::Mul<T, Output = T> + ops::Div<T, Output = T> + ops::Rem<T, Output = T>
 {}
```

Alright, this trait should cover us. Mind that it's missing a `ops::Neg` bound because this bound is not implemented for unsigned traits; so if we need `Neg` we'll have to add it; but it's easy enough.

As for the issue about constants, well indeed working your way from `zero` upwards is insane. It's quite the reason why the `Zero` and `One` traits are still unstable.

The generic conversion traits are `convert::From` and `convert::Into`, and that is what one would use.

So let us reformulate `is_divisible`, and finally implement `is_even`:

```
fn is_divisible<T>(x: T, by: T) -> bool
    where T: Arithmetic
{
    (x % by) == 0.into()
}

fn is_even<T>(x: T) -> bool
    where T: Arithmetic
{
    is_divisible(x, 2.into())
}
```

And really, those two functions seem both perfectly clear whilst still being generic.

[Full code here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cf63456afd343144c7e6&version=stable)

---

Now, we might argue that creating this `Arithmetic` trait is a long-winded way of getting to `is_even`. It is. However:

- if you only need `is_even`, obviously you care little if it takes 6 bounds; it's a one off
- if you need multiple generic functions working on numerics, then the small cost of creating this trait and function are negligible in the grand scheme of things

In short, it works. And it's really not that onerous.